# Сортировка отдельных элементов списка в Python

Tags: python, функции, сортировка, список

Дан список. Хочу написать функцию, которая сортирует положительные элементы, при этом оставляя отрицательные на своих местах. Например: для списка `[-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]` функция должна возвращать `[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]`. Как можно это реализовать? Пробовал через цикл добавлять элементы в пустые списки по условию `i < 0`, отсортировать второй список и сложить получившиеся списки, но не понимаю как это должно работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы заменил в начале положительные элементы на какой-нибудь символ(пробел например " ") а все числа больше нуля сохранил в другой список, отсортировал и заменял бы обратно уже сортированными.

```
lst = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]


def mySort(a):
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] > 0:
            temp.append(a[i])
            a[i] = " "

    temp.sort(reverse=True) #сортировка в обратном порядке

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == ' ':
            a[i] = temp.pop()
    return a
print(mySort(lst))

[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Comment: У Вас список не изменился

Comment: с первым вариантом сработало:

```
def mySort(a):
    b = []
    for i, j in enumerate(a):
        if a[i] > 0:
            b.append(a[i])
            a[i] = '+'
    b.sort(reverse = True)
    for i, j in enumerate(a):
        if a[i] == '+':
            a[i] = b.pop()
    return a
```

Comment: да , что-то я накосячил  с правками. Вернул назад всё.

Answer (score 3):

Вот вариант через `Numpy`. Наверняка можно ещё короче, но сходу не соображу:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180])
a[a > 0] = np.sort(a[a > 0])
print(a)
# [ -1 150 160 170  -1  -1 180 190]
```

Тут главное что всё совершенно понятно - берём элементы, которые больше нуля и прямо на их место присваиваем их же, но в отсортированном виде.

К сожалению, со стандартным питоновским `list` такое нельзя сделать, поэтому приходится использовать `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте использовать модуль numpy:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
arr = np.array(lst)
arr[np.nonzero(arr>0)] = np.sort(arr[arr>0])
res = arr.tolist()
```

тогда res у вас будет:

```
[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Answer (score 1):

Для небольших списков - доработанная сортировка выбором:

```
def sortplus(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-1, 0, -1):
        if l[i] > 0:
            imax = i
            for j in range(i):
                if l[j] > l[imax]:
                    imax = j
            if imax != i:
                l[i], l[imax] = l[imax], l[i]
    print(l)

sortplus([-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180])

>>[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```